# SSl Handshake Successful c++

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to know the functions which establish the SSL connection from windows.. I am writing a code to know whether the SMTP uses SSL of TLS ..i am able to find get TLS because encryption happens after handshake... i want to know   about SSl .. please help me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

[OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) is the most common library used for SSL.

Comment: thank you which Library is used  for Windows. does windows uses Open SSL

Comment: OpenSSL can be used in Windows. Google `openssl windows` and you will find executable installers.